# Ejecutar 2 veces un mismo hilo Java

Tags: java, hilos

Tengo un inconveniente y busco ayuda. Necesito obligatoriamente ejecutar muchas veces un mismo hilo y me sale el error

```
(java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException)
```

¿alguien conoce alguna forma de hacerlo ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Byron, te aconsejo que cuando preguntes agregues código como texto y no como imagen, saludos.

Comment: Las imágenes, no sólo hacen imposible copiar tu código para probarlo, sino que también pueden ser difíciles de leer (pensemos en celulares que no definan bien la imagen o en personas con problemas de vista). ¿Podrías por favor incluir el código y el mensaje de error como texto? Encontrarás el enlace para **[edit]** debajo de tu pregunta. Luego de pegarlo, hay que seleccionar el código completamente y hacer click en el botón `{  }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obtienes `IllegalThreadStateException` porque se esta llamado el método run() pero el estado del Thread no lo permite.

Lo que se realiza comúnmente es crear un nuevo Thread, por ejemplo:

```
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
  new Thread(String.valueOf(i)){
    public void run(){
      System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread: " + getName());
    }
  }.start();
}
```

---

Si deseas crear una clase puedes crear una clase que implemente [**Runnable**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html):

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable{
    int id;
    public MyThread(int i){
        this.id = i;
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Run: "+ Thread.currentThread().getName()); 
        }catch(Exception err){
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

De esta forma ejecutar varias veces un Thread:

```
 for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
        System.out.println("Ejecutando Thread:" + i);
        MyThread thread = new MyThread(i);        
 }
```